# Sharepoint Multiple document upload not available to users

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

We are using WSS 3.0. Users have reported the Multiple document upload menu item is not available.

These users are working with IE8 / Office 2007 with their documents.

I don't know where to look at. On the same Sharepoint site some users have the menu enable and others dont.

Where should we look to enable the menu for these users?

Comment: try running the share point site in I.E. - compatibility mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the **Windows SharePoint Services Support** component (under 'Office Tools') has been installed by the Office setup program. This installs an ActiveX control that provides functionality such as support for uploading multiple documents within IE. If it does show as installed use the **Repair** option so that Office setup can ensure it is installed correctly.

You can check if the upload ActiveX control is installed correctly by going to Manage Add-Ons in IE8. Set the filter to show 'All Add-Ons'. Under Toolbars and Extensions look for the **STSUpld UploadCtl Class** and ensure it is enabled. It should have a major version of 12, for example 12.0.4518.1014.

As [Duey mentioned](https://serverfault.com/questions/60035/sharepoint-multiple-document-upload-not-available-to-users/60286#60286), also ensure the user can run ActiveX controls within IE. In the security zone that applies to the SharePoint site, ensure **Run ActiveX control and plug-ins** and **Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting** are set to at least Prompt, if not Enable. A quick check is to temporarily add the SharePoint site address to the Trusted Sites zone.

Answer (score 2):

For the users that don't have the multi upload option you need to enable the ActiveX Control for multi file upload.  when they load the upload page they should get the yellow notification bar at the top of the page that the page is trying to load the ActiveX.  The user must click and select to run the ActiveX, also they must have the user rights to do so.